# Kafka Spout ERROR

Tags: java, logging, apache-kafka, apache-storm, hortonworks-data-platform

Hello everybody hope u re doing good!
Plz help me on this ERROR I d on't understand anything 
I m working on hortonworks sandbox on real time processing using storm and kafka, when I deploy the topology and I send data with the Kafka producer witch I can read it with the Kafka console consumer but I got this error on my storm UI!

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: kafka.javaapi.consumer.SimpleConsumer.<init>(Ljava/lang/String;IIILjava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)V at storm.kafka.DynamicPartitionConnections.register(DynamicPartit
```

And when I check the log I get this

```
2016-05-11 05:55:47.707 b.s.util [ERROR] Async loop died!
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: kafka.javaapi.consumer.SimpleConsumer.<init>(Ljava/lang/String;IIILjava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)V
    at storm.kafka.DynamicPartitionConnections.register(DynamicPartitionConnections.java:60) ~[stormjar.jar:?]
    at storm.kafka.PartitionManager.<init>(PartitionManager.java:66) ~[stormjar.jar:?]
    at storm.kafka.ZkCoordinator.refresh(ZkCoordinator.java:98) ~[stormjar.jar:?]
    at storm.kafka.ZkCoordinator.getMyManagedPartitions(ZkCoordinator.java:69) ~[stormjar.jar:?]
    at storm.kafka.KafkaSpout.nextTuple(KafkaSpout.java:138) ~[stormjar.jar:?]
    at backtype.storm.daemon.executor$fn__7177$fn__7192$fn__7221.invoke(executor.clj:596) ~[storm-core-0.10.0.2.4.0.0-169.jar:0.10.0.2.4.0.0-169]
    at backtype.storm.util$async_loop$fn__544.invoke(util.clj:475) [storm-core-0.10.0.2.4.0.0-169.jar:0.10.0.2.4.0.0-169]
    at clojure.lang.AFn.run(AFn.java:22) [clojure-1.6.0.jar:?]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [?:1.7.0_95]
2016-05-11 05:55:47.713 b.s.d.executor [ERROR] 
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: kafka.javaapi.consumer.SimpleConsumer.<init>(Ljava/lang/String;IIILjava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)V
    at storm.kafka.DynamicPartitionConnections.register(DynamicPartitionConnections.java:60) ~[stormjar.jar:?]
    at storm.kafka.PartitionManager.<init>(PartitionManager.java:66) ~[stormjar.jar:?]
    at storm.kafka.ZkCoordinator.refresh(ZkCoordinator.java:98) ~[stormjar.jar:?]
    at storm.kafka.ZkCoordinator.getMyManagedPartitions(ZkCoordinator.java:69) ~[stormjar.jar:?]
    at storm.kafka.KafkaSpout.nextTuple(KafkaSpout.java:138) ~[stormjar.jar:?]
    at backtype.storm.daemon.executor$fn__7177$fn__7192$fn__7221.invoke(executor.clj:596) ~[storm-core-0.10.0.2.4.0.0-169.jar:0.10.0.2.4.0.0-169]
    at backtype.storm.util$async_loop$fn__544.invoke(util.clj:475) [storm-core-0.10.0.2.4.0.0-169.jar:0.10.0.2.4.0.0-169]
    at clojure.lang.AFn.run(AFn.java:22) [clojure-1.6.0.jar:?]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [?:1.7.0_95]
2016-05-11 05:55:47.749 b.s.util [ERROR] Halting process: ("Worker died")
java.lang.RuntimeException: ("Worker died")
    at backtype.storm.util$exit_process_BANG_.doInvoke(util.clj:332) [storm-core-0.10.0.2.4.0.0-169.jar:0.10.0.2.4.0.0-169]
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:423) [clojure-1.6.0.jar:?]
    at backtype.storm.daemon.worker$fn__7818$fn__7819.invoke(worker.clj:636) [storm-core-0.10.0.2.4.0.0-169.jar:0.10.0.2.4.0.0-169]
    at backtype.storm.daemon.executor$mk_executor_data$fn__7078$fn__7079.invoke(executor.clj:256) [storm-core-0.10.0.2.4.0.0-169.jar:0.10.0.2.4.0.0-169]
    at backtype.storm.util$async_loop$fn__544.invoke(util.clj:485) [storm-core-0.10.0.2.4.0.0-169.jar:0.10.0.2.4.0.0-169]
    at clojure.lang.AFn.run(AFn.java:22) [clojure-1.6.0.jar:?]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [?:1.7.0_95]

2016-05-11 05:55:59.156 b.s.util [ERROR] Async loop died!
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: kafka.javaapi.consumer.SimpleConsumer.<init>(Ljava/lang/String;IIILjava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)V
    at storm.kafka.DynamicPartitionConnections.register(DynamicPartitionConnections.java:60) ~[stormjar.jar:?]
    at storm.kafka.PartitionManager.<init>(PartitionManager.java:66) ~[stormjar.jar:?]
    at storm.kafka.ZkCoordinator.refresh(ZkCoordinator.java:98) ~[stormjar.jar:?]
    at storm.kafka.ZkCoordinator.getMyManagedPartitions(ZkCoordinator.java:69) ~[stormjar.jar:?]
    at storm.kafka.KafkaSpout.nextTuple(KafkaSpout.java:138) ~[stormjar.jar:?]
    at backtype.storm.daemon.executor$fn__7177$fn__7192$fn__7221.invoke(executor.clj:596) ~[storm-core-0.10.0.2.4.0.0-169.jar:0.10.0.2.4.0.0-169]
    at backtype.storm.util$async_loop$fn__544.invoke(util.clj:475) [storm-core-0.10.0.2.4.0.0-169.jar:0.10.0.2.4.0.0-169]
    at clojure.lang.AFn.run(AFn.java:22) [clojure-1.6.0.jar:?]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [?:1.7.0_95]
2016-05-11 05:55:59.162 b.s.d.executor [ERROR] 
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: kafka.javaapi.consumer.SimpleConsumer.<init>(Ljava/lang/String;IIILjava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)V
    at storm.kafka.DynamicPartitionConnections.register(DynamicPartitionConnections.java:60) ~[stormjar.jar:?]
    at storm.kafka.PartitionManager.<init>(PartitionManager.java:66) ~[stormjar.jar:?]
    at storm.kafka.ZkCoordinator.refresh(ZkCoordinator.java:98) ~[stormjar.jar:?]
    at storm.kafka.ZkCoordinator.getMyManagedPartitions(ZkCoordinator.java:69) ~[stormjar.jar:?]
    at storm.kafka.KafkaSpout.nextTuple(KafkaSpout.java:138) ~[stormjar.jar:?]
    at backtype.storm.daemon.executor$fn__7177$fn__7192$fn__7221.invoke(executor.clj:596) ~[storm-core-0.10.0.2.4.0.0-169.jar:0.10.0.2.4.0.0-169]
    at backtype.storm.util$async_loop$fn__544.invoke(util.clj:475) [storm-core-0.10.0.2.4.0.0-169.jar:0.10.0.2.4.0.0-169]
    at clojure.lang.AFn.run(AFn.java:22) [clojure-1.6.0.jar:?]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [?:1.7.0_95]
2016-05-11 05:55:59.195 b.s.util [ERROR] Halting process: ("Worker died")
java.lang.RuntimeException: ("Worker died")
    at backtype.storm.util$exit_process_BANG_.doInvoke(util.clj:332) [storm-core-0.10.0.2.4.0.0-169.jar:0.10.0.2.4.0.0-169]
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:423) [clojure-1.6.0.jar:?]
    at backtype.storm.daemon.worker$fn__7818$fn__7819.invoke(worker.clj:636) [storm-core-0.10.0.2.4.0.0-169.jar:0.10.0.2.4.0.0-169]
    at backtype.storm.daemon.executor$mk_executor_data$fn__7078$fn__7079.invoke(executor.clj:256) [storm-core-0.10.0.2.4.0.0-169.jar:0.10.0.2.4.0.0-169]
    at backtype.storm.util$async_loop$fn__544.invoke(util.clj:485) [storm-core-0.10.0.2.4.0.0-169.jar:0.10.0.2.4.0.0-169]
    at clojure.lang.AFn.run(AFn.java:22) [clojure-1.6.0.jar:?]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [?:1.7.0_95]
```

Thank u all for helping me

Comment: What versions of Kafka and Storm are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Check the stack version and the kafka version in your pom. This is happening because of version mismatch.